GIt bash its not starting in the current workspace folder
I updated my windows 11 and noticed that git bash is no longer opening in the current folder I'm working in, it always opens in /c/Users/user
If I click on Git bash here or open a project in vscode it opens in this folder, I've tried everything but nothing makes it open in the current folder. Before, when opening a project in vscode, gitbash already started in the project folder.
I've tried everything I found on the internet, I already uninstalled and installed again, would anyone have any ideas?
I hope git bash works properly

i made this https://graphite.dev/guides/git-change-home-directory-git-bash and worked
